# Check if request came from a webview or browser on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, webview

Is there a way to check (server side) if a request came from a webview or the native browser on iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 1):

If you control the application that has the webview, you can install an `NSURLProtocol` that will modify the requests before sending them out. This can change the user agent, or add some other custom header that you can interrogate. Of course this is not a security measure; anyone could craft the same header, but it would allow you to customize your response based on whether the client is claiming to be your app.

I keep meaning to blog on `NSURLProtocol` because there aren't a lot of examples out there, but for now you can take a look at how PandoraBoy does it in [ProxyURLProtocol](https://github.com/PandoraBoy/PandoraBoy/blob/master/ProxyURLProtocol.m).

Answer (score 0):

Webviews use Safari framework, so they report Safari for iPhone as user-agent. Requests from Safari or webview won't be any different.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the *user agent* string contains the word **Safari** then its from *Mobile Safari* browser for sure.

FYI:

In *UIWebView or WkWebView* user agent string can be changed programatically